# Why does the Setinterval Timer stops with Google Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a form with a simple status **div** tag and a form which posts to my server.  Upon post my server does actions which can take a long time (i.e. 30+ seconds).  So I wanted to add a status label to provide feedback.  I accomplished this with a javascript **setinterval**:

```
<script language=javascript>
var id=self.setInterval("getstatus()",1000);
</script>
```

The javascript function **getstatus** makes a call to my server, gets the current status, and updates the **div** tag.  Everything works fine on Firefox and Interet Explorer.  But with Chrome the Timer stops firing until the function called on the Post is finished; essentially rendering my status feedback useless.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should replace `"getstatus()"` with `getstatus` to prevent invoking the `eval` interpreter superfluously.

Comment: you might try something like: `var id=setInterval(function() {self.getstatus()}, 1000};` - just an idea.

Comment: Is your post function being run synchronously?  If so, then this is expected behavior because there's only one Javascript thread of execution at a time.  If so, the obvious answer would be to change your post to be asychronous.

Comment: jfriend00 - I suspected it had to do something with asynchronous.  I will look at changing to a asynchronous post.  This is something I don't know about.

Comment: Replace *setInterval*, with *setTimeout* and have the function call itself. That way you can call it 10 seconds after the last one returned, rather then just calling it every 10 seconds regardless of when or whether the prevoius one returned.